# What are the differences between the four racial T3 Cruisers?

Tags: eve-online

I've heard that Loki is the best SC when it comes to PvP, while Tengu excels at PvE, and I haven't heard that much of Legion and Proteus.

Besides the obvious racial traits such as "Amarr have armor tanks and lasers, Gallente have drones etc.", what are the main differences between the four, and why are they better at certain tasks than the ones of other races?

**Long story short**, what makes Tengu so good in PvE, what makes Loki so good in PvP, and what the hell are the other two made for?

Comment: Man, the Tengu lovefest is still on as of the end of 2016. I was going to ask why people like it so much compared to the others, but found this question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion since the Heavy Missile changes, the Tengu isn't the "best" mission runner anymore. It's not "bad" since you can still fit it up with HAMs but it's a lot more balanced than it was. The Tengu is so loved because it's a true jack of all trades.

Here is a breakdown of the pros and cons of each of the strategic cruisers;

**Legion** (Amarr)

- the good: Highly versatile, great damage projection, can be fitted as a neuter, good tank in almost any setup, can fit HAMs, Legion armour boosts <3, probably best armour T3 for running sites
- the bad: No real EWAR or tackle benefit unlike the others (Loki webs, Proteus points, Tengu jams) limit its usefulness in PvP, bad when set up with a cloak

**Loki** (Minmatar)

- the good: Brings the most utility, awesome webs, can be armour or shield tanked, good with cloak subsystem if you mean to bring utility, probably most useful out of the four with capitals on field
- the bad: DPS is pretty poor

**Proteus** (Gallente)

- the good: Best cloaky ship while maintaining high DPS, especially with blasters, blasters > everything for close range DPS.
- the bad: Can't fill many roles, not versatile

**Tengu** (Caldari)

- the good: Good mission and site runner for solo play, jack of all trades
- the bad: Not got a great shield, heavy missiles are quite poor since the nerf, average DPS, doesn't really master anything

Comment: What exactly is "Damage Projection", and what do you mean when you say that some ships are better with cloaks than others?

Comment: T3 cruisers can use covert cloaks with the correct subsystem installed, this subsystem sits in the offensive slot so is at the expense of DPS. Some ships are better with this subsystem fitted than others. For example, fitting a Legion to use a cloak sacrifices too much DPS in many people's opinions.

Comment: Ah, arrite.Also, while we're at it, I am training for Amarr skills and weapons, and in a month or so, my corp will be moving into WH-Space, so I was wondering if I should start working towards the Legion (since I've heard T3s do wonders in WH Space, and the fact that they make decent explorers).

On another note, can you refit subsystems on assembled T3s?

Comment: T3s are versitile which is the main advantage of them... Yes you can switch out subsystems after you have assembled a T3

Comment: Damage projection is the ability to project your damage :P. In other words, 1500 dps doesn't do any good if you can only hit 2km and they are 10km. While Amarr can't beat blasters in raw damage, they are very strong at causing damage further out without losing a ton of effectiveness.

Answer (score -1):

The HAM Tengu I fly reaches speeds in excess of 1040 DPS with furies at 41k and 700+ dps with javelins which shoot out to 71 K...

At 700 m/s it takes virtually no damage against massive fire, and the medium faction shield booster makes it Uber Sweet. :D

Make no mistake the HAM Tengu, was always a winner, and is now more powerful than ever. It is a contender for ANY level 4 mission runner.

Low sig radius missiles with good dps at long range, and great dps at short range. As long as you kill frigs first, you are unlikely to die in any prudent mission running scenario! Let me put it another way: I have L5 Marauder skills, all races, and I still prefer the Tengu! :)

Comment: Not really sure if it's worth thumbing. You just kinda brag about how awesome your tengu is, while I'm asking why I should use tengu over something else (or something else instead of tengu).